# wpf reportviewer EF

Tags: wpf, entity-framework, reportviewer, rdlc

Looked all day for a tutorial for a WPF app with a RDLC report using Entity Framework with no luck.
Found a good tutorial only with SQLCLient [link](http://kishor-naik-dotnet.blogspot.com/2011/06/wpf-rdlc-report-in-wpf.html)
The strange thing is that in my WPF app my ReportViewer doesn't have a smart tag [photo](http://weblogs.asp.net/blogs/rajbk/image_thumb_786BD626.png)

**Q:** How can I populate with data a rdlc report using EF ?

Comment: I want to know this as well as we transition more and more to EF.

Answer (score 0):

Add reference to Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms.dll version 10.0.0.0

Mark-up code:

```
<Window ...
    xmlns:RV="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms;assembly=Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms"Title="WPF_RDLC" >
<Grid>
    <WindowsFormsHost  Name="wiFormsHost1">
        <RV:ReportViewer x:Name="Report1">
        </RV:ReportViewer>
    </WindowsFormsHost>
</Grid>
```

Code-behind

```
private void DisplayReport()
    {
        WPF_Entities db = new WPF_Entities();
        try
        {
            var qry = db.People.AsEnumerable(); // 
            Report1.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Local;
            Report1.LocalReport.ReportEmbeddedResource = "WPFApp1.Reports.People.rdlc"; // .Reports if the report isin the Reports folder not in the root
            ReportDataSource dataSource = new ReportDataSource("DS_people", qry);
            Report1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
            Report1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(dataSource);

            Report1.RefreshReport();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Add a RDLC report (in the Reports folder) with a DataSource file(.xsd) that contains the entity People and the name "People.rdlc" that has a DataSet name DS_people